# .htaccess template

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2, http-status-code-301

I made an .htaccess template; is there anything else that should be added or changed?

```
# DEFAULTS
ServerSignature Off
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
DefaultLanguage en-US
SetEnv Europe/Belgrade
SetEnv SERVER_ADMIN chrisp@dejan.com.au

# Rewrites
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Redirect to WWW
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^serpentineseo.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.serpentineseo.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# Cache media files
<filesMatch "\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png|ico|swf|js)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000, public"
</filesMatch>

<FilesMatch "\.(js|css|pdf|swf)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800"
</FilesMatch>

<FilesMatch "\.(html|htm|txt)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=600"
</FilesMatch>

# DONT CACHE
<FilesMatch "\.(pl|php|cgi|spl|scgi|fcgi)$">
Header unset Cache-Control
</FilesMatch>

# Deny access to .htaccess
<Files .htaccess>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>
```

Comment: This is an ideal candidate for serverfault.

Answer (score 2):

Turn Off ETags [1]

```
FileETag None
```

ServerTokens Prod, ServerSignature Off [2]

```
ServerTokens prod
ServerSignature Off
```

[1]: http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/apache-speed-etags.html Turn off ETags

[2]: http://www.petefreitag.com/item/419.cfm ServerTokens Prod, ServerSignature Off

Comment: Thanks, just one question.
If ServerSignature Off smacks the software version from being showed why show anything at all with ServerTokens prod ?

Comment: The server version will still be sent in response headers.

Comment: Sorry, ServerTokens can not be used in VirtualHost context. Set it globally.